# is there a function like access() but for a specific user id?

Tags: c, linux, freepascal

The Linux function [`access()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/access) allows me to check file permissions for the **current** user.

Is there a similar function that gives me the same information - but instead of checking the current user it checks the permissions of any given  system user?

Something like `int access_for(const char *pathname, uid_t uid, int mode);` or whatever

I can't use [`seteuid()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/seteuid) as I need this for a multithreaded process (POSIX threads) which would affect all threads at the same time. That's why I need to check file permissions myself.

**Edit:** The process itself is known/assumed to have *at least* the privileges of the relevant user. So, in theory I could also walk the file system and calculate the rights by hand, but I'd need something much more efficient as the check needs to be done several (up to hundreds) times per second. Possible?

Comment: You might be able to use `stat()` and `getgrgid()` to figure out if a user can access the file . I can't write up a decent answer ATM, might attempt it later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Linux, fundamentally all `set*id` operations are thread-local. This is wrong and non-conforming (the standard specifies that a *process*, not a thread, has ids that are set by these functions) and the userspace code (in libc) has to work around the issue via delicate and error-prone logic to change all the thread uids in a synchronized way. However, you may be able to invoke the syscall directly (via `syscall()`) to change the ids for just one thread.

Also, Linux has the concept of "filesystem uid" set by the `setfsuid` function. If I'm not mistaken, libc leaves this one thread-local, since it's not specified by any standard (and thus does not have any requirements imposed on it) and since the whole purpose of this function is thread-local use like what you're doing. I think this second option is much better if it works.

Finally, there's one solution that's completely portable but slow: `fork` then use `seteuid` in the child, call `access` there, pass the result back to the parent, and `_exit`.

Comment: Whoa. This is big news for me. Can you reference any web site that discusses this in depth? I fear this could lead to other problems when I bypass `libc` (what do you think about this?)

Comment: Yes, I agree bypassing libc is a bad idea; I just mentioned it for completeness. However the `setfsuid` solution is not bypassing libc; as far as I know, glibc and other libcs pass it through to the kernel, leaving the "fsuid" thread-local.

Comment: Actually, the problem might be `access` - if I'm not mistaken, it uses the *real* user-id, not the effective one, and probably not the filesystem one. However you might be able to just perform `open` instead.

Comment: You're not mistaken, but there's also `eaccess` or `euidaccess`

Comment: You'll need to check whether those use the fsuid though.

Comment: I don't need `access()` when all file accesses are controlled by the O/S itself. Before reading your answer I thought I have to wrap all file accesses with explicit permission checks. Leaving the check to the O/S using setfsuid() in my multi-threaded process would be just perfect.

Comment: Yes, what you just said. :-) Using `access` is almost always a mistake; it can have extremely dangerous race conditions. Just use `setfsuid` and then attempt the operation you want to do, and check for failure.

Comment: @R..: it seems that for `setfsuid()` to work I cannot use `seteuid()` to keep the process running with restricted permissions while being "idle" (ie. outside a block that's specifically restricted with `setfsuid()`) because that way any `setfsuid()` call would fail, right?

Comment: Using `seteuid` to "keep the process running with restricted permissions while idle" does not actually provide any significant security. As long as it still has a real uid of root, an attacker who has found a code-execution vulnerability can easily regain root. Are you sure you need to be doing that?

Answer (score 2):

not sure how it could work. if you're running as user X, you couldn't reliably check if user Y has access to something, because the check would be done under YOUR permissions. You may not have access to something that `Y` does, meaning you'd get a false negative.

Comment: Good point (+1). Also, being able to check whether another user has access to something would be a potential security flaw.

Comment: Good point. Anyway I need this for a daemon that (unfortunately needs to) run with higher privileges (*similar* to a web server for multiple hosts), so this would not be a problem. If necessary, it could even run as `root`.

Comment: if running as root, then no problem. Fork off a separate process, do the suid stuff there to assume the other user's permissions, then do the access check?

Comment: Would probably work, but I need something highly efficient as I need to do this check several times per second. :(

Answer (score 2):

Beware of [TOCTOU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use). If you check NOW that a file can be accessed, it doesn't mean that NOW it can (or can't), because the time it took you to read those words between "NOW" and "NOW", the file privileges may well have changed.

So, the CORRECT solution is to run in a thread/process as the user that you want to access the file as. Otherwise, you run a risk of "the file privileges changed while you were working" problem.

Of course, this applies to any type of access to "things that may be restricted based on who I am running as".

Comment: You are of course right and it good to mention it here, altough I'm well aware of this problem and could live with it.